# running an async task only after another one has finished

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have an async function that I run on a cluster. Also, I would like to use another function that is only started after the first function finished, and does some processing depending on the outcomes of the first function:

```py
async def process(x):
    await do_something(x)

async def postprocess(x):
    await do_something_else(x)

# run task
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(process(x))
task = loop.create_task(postprocess(x))
```

Is this the right way to launch one after the other?

Comment: " to use another function that is only started after the first function finished" - just `await` them sequentially

Comment: ok so `await process(x) await postprocess(x)` in some `async def main(x)` would do the job?